How to Validate TextBox when AjaxFileUpload "Upload" Button is Clicked
Please know that I'm a complete noob without any kind of web dev experience. This also seems like something that would be wanted pretty frequently, so I very well might be missing something simple in my too-many hours of Googling.
I have a web form with some text boxes for user info and an AjaxFileUpload control. I want to check that a TextBox is filled in when the "Upload" button in the AdjaxFileUpload control is hit.
I'm successfully using the OnClientUploadCompleteAll of the upload control and a Java function that triggers and a hidden button to do some things after the upload.
I was hoping to use the OnClientUploadStart to do something similar for checking the TextBox. The commented code below are things I've tried after searching around for things, but with no joy. I'm also thinking there may not be a way to do this because when the JSUpldStart function fires the "Upload" button has already turned into a "Cancel" button in the upload control.
I've tried playing with some asp.net validation things but couldn't make those work. Again, noob, was probably missing something as I only had validation happening AFTER the upload and it was cancelling the post upload code that had been working. :o/
Thanks for reading.
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
    OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete"
    OnClientUploadCompleteAll="JSUpldDoneAll"
    OnClientUploadStart="JSUpldStart"
    Width="50%" />

function JSUpldStart(sender, args) {
    /*alert("JSUPldStart")*/
    if (TxtUplBy.value == "") {
        alert("It's blank.")
        /*args.cancel(true);    Cancel is not a function*/
        //throw ("Please fill in name.");
        //return false;
        //args.set_cancel(True);        Error: True is not defined
        //args.set_cancel(true);        Error: set_cancel is not a function
        //args.set_cancel=true          Did absolutely nothing.
    }
}


I never was able to get the dang cancel to work for AjaxFileUpload, it always just continued and uploaded the file.
I ended up pursuing Yuriy's idea above of disabling the AjaxFileUpload unless the field was filled in, and was able to get his code above working. The problem was that once a file was selected in the AjaxFileUpload disabling and enabling it made funky things happen, like the "Upload" button turning into a cancel button.
I ended up putting the AjaxFileUpload in a panel and used the attached JavaScript routine to check the field, then used jquery .attr to set the disabled attributes on the panel, which makes it impossible to click on or tab to the AjaxFileUpload.
For visual indication I overlapped a transparent div with alight gray color to "gray-out the AjaxFileUpload.
If any of this is bad practice I'd be interested to know. As I mentioned at the beginning, I've never done anything like this before.
Thanks to everyone for answering.

I have tested with the below code, it's working. Please integrate in your webform and verify.
Note: On browser, after select a file, click on Upload button.
<asp:TextBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" id="TxtUplBy"/>

<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnClientUploadStart="validateTextBox" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateTextBox(sender, args) {
    var textBox = document.getElementById('<%= txtBox.ClientID %>');
    if (textBox.value.trim() == '') {
        alert('Please fill in the TextBox before uploading a file.');
        sender.cancelUpload(); // Cancel the file upload
    }
}

Note: Ending script tag is not displaying here in the above code, seems there is an issue with stack overflow. Ensure you add it in your code.

Thanks for responding, but I really need to try and do it BEFORE the upload. On completion of the upload, an email is sent to our production team so we know somebody uploaded, sorry I hadn't mentioned that in the original post.

Hello @KenKrugh
I have updated the above response. Please check.

The original code I posted was pretty much what you have here and seemed to be working because after hitting the upload button in the AjaxFileUpload control I got the alert in my java function that the box was empty. But the args.set_cancel(true); line wasn't stopping the upload. And when javascript debugging is enabled I get an error saying "Uncaught TypeError TypeError: args.set_cancel is not a function." I also don't get "set_cancel" in the Intellisense when I type a period after args. Could there be something else, someplace else that is keeping the set_cancel from working?

Regarding arg.set_cancel intellisense, It could be your IDE/Editor issue.
However, I have updated above code to use sender.cancelUpload(); instead arg.set_cancel(). You can try with the above updated code it should work.

Perhaps you can try setting the enabled property of the button to False until the text box's .text property is not empty, this basically just makes it so you cannot press or focus the button. So for example I have these asp.net text box and button:
<div>
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" id="tbRequired" OnTextChanged="Upload_Check"/>
 <asp:Button runat="server" id="Upload" text="Upload"/>
</div>

And then in the back I have:
Protected Sub OnLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Upload.Enabled = False
End Sub

Protected Sub Upload_Check(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    If tbRequired.Text <> "" Then
        Upload.Enabled = True
    else
        Upload.Enabled = False
    End IF
End Sub

The first method is run within a standard page_load method which runs at the first load of the webpage. (Handles Mybase.load, Not IsPostBack)
The second method will run when the text within the textbox is changed and will check to see if the textbox has been populated, if it has it will enable the button to be able to be pressed, and if it is still empty the button will remain unclickable
It looks like this when there is no text entered

And when it has text

Sorry the code is in VB but JS also supports the .Enabled property

You can try this (not tested and written from memory)
function enableDisableUpoad(value) {
   const enabled = !!value;
   const extender = $find("<%= AjaxFileUpload1.ClientID %>");
   extender.set_enabled(enabled);
   extender.enableControls(enabled);
}

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="MyTextBox" onchange="enableDisableUpoad(this.value)" />
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
  ... />


This would be great if I could get it to work. Intellisense is showing it's OnTextChanged and I'm getting a compilation errors that enableDisableUpoad is not part of the form, and that "this" is not declared. Is there something else I need to add to use OnTextChanged in this way? Thanks

There is no OnTextChanged in my code. it's client onchange handler

I just created a C# webforms asp.net project (mine is VB) just to see and it shows no onchange, only OnTextChanged. Are you working in VisualStudio like I am?
